# コンパイラエラー C2872 あいまいなシンボルです。

Tags: c++, visual-studio, .net, c++-cli

コンパイルエラーが解消出来ません。
ご教授下さい。

■コンパイルエラー内容
error C2872: 'MarketplaceWebServiceProducts' : あいまいなシンボルです

■やりたいこと
AmazonのAPI「Marketplace Web Service API (MWS)」のHello world

以下ページの右上 オレンジ色の「Download」ボタンから入手できる
「MWSProducts_2011-10-01_v2017-03-22.dll」の使用
https://developer.amazonservices.jp/doc/products/products/v20111001/cSharp.html

■DLLの使用
Visual Studioの対象プロジェクトのプロパティから、
上記DLLの参照を追加しました

■コーディング

```
using namespace MarketplaceWebServiceProducts;//←ここはコンパイルOK
using namespace MarketplaceWebServiceProducts::Mock;//←★ここで上記コンパイルエラー
```

■ご質問
上位の「MarketplaceWebServiceProducts」が正常なのに、
下位の「Mock」を付けるとあいまいなシンボルになるのはなぜでしょうか。
解決策をご教授ください。（可能であれば実装をご提供ください）

■環境
Visual Studio
.Net 4.0
C++/Cli

Comment: MWSは詳しくないですがエラーだけ見ると、上位のものに下位のMockも含まれていてネームスペースが競合しているのではないでしょうか？

Comment: ご回答誠にありがとうございます

Comment: 理屈は分かるのですが、具体的にどのように解決すればよろしいでしょうか？
XXXXX::MarketplaceWebServiceProducts::Mock;

Comment: というような感じですか？よくわかっておりません

Comment: 言っても仕方が無いかもしれませんが、なぜC++なのでしょう？ 結局 C#用DLLを使うなら呼び出し元もC#の方がとっても楽だと思うのですが。[C#でAmazonのMWSを使用して,マケプレの出品情報を取得する](http://nanoappli.com/blog/archives/4409)

Comment: マルチポスト：https://qiita.com/kakusuyo/items/7c2b619adde3c7232c9a、https://teratail.com/questions/169698、https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q10202144490

Answer (score 2):

C++言語ではコンパイル時にヘッダーファイルを参照し、リンク時にライブラリと結合します。ところが.NETアセンブリはDLLファイルで完結しておりヘッダーファイルが存在しません。
そこでVisual C++では、[#usingディレクティブ](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/hash-using-directive-cpp?view=vs-2017)が用意されています。

```
#using "MWSProducts_2011-10-01_v2017-03-22.dll"
```

と記述すると、C++コンパイラーは.NETアセンブリを読み込み、相当するヘッダーファイルへ変換し`#include`されたかのように扱います。[コンパイルオプション`/FU`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/fu-name-forced-hash-using-file?view=vs-2017)でも同等の結果を得ることができます。

---

> Visual Studioの対象プロジェクトのプロパティから、
>   上記DLLの参照を追加しました

上記の通りですので、残念ながら参照方法が間違っています。